# Endpoint HandShake exception

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, endpoint

I am getting

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/EchoChamber/echo' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302
```

I started exact same project, as here: [link.](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/12/websockets-an-introduction/)
I am using Tomcat 6. How fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSocket clients expect that `101 Switching Protocols` is returned from a server, but your endpoint returns `302 Found`. Check the settings of your server.